# A way to link to a class,a method, especially a specific code line in C# comment

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, hyperlink, comments

I want to build sort of documentation using links in code that point to a target. The target could be a `Class` or a `Method` or a specific code line. (**pointing to a specific code line is the most important**)

I thought of an extension for VS2010 or a specific comment tag.

Is there any way to make links of this kind ?

Comment: Javadoc was able to do precisely this kind of thing.   When Microsoft released .Net 1.1, they tried to mimic Javadoc with "NDoc".  Then killed NDoc in favor of "Sandcastle": http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2006/02/16/ndoc-project-stalled-no-version-2-microsoft.aspx. Their current XML thing is, frankly, a mess... SUGGESTION: consider using [Doxygen] (http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/) instead.

Comment: @HichemC, try [this](http://hyperaddin.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I just tried it and I think it works fine - just register the add-in and read the Help.htm to learn how to use it. If you have any troubles (because it is built for VS 2005 & 2008) you can just rebuild the solution (it's open source) and it should work fine.

Comment: @paulsm4 that comment seems a bit ranty..

Comment: ... especially as NDoc wasn't written by Microsoft, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: unless you commit your code, there is no way to link a specific line of code since there is no real pointer to a line. Line 80 become 81 if someone inserts a blank line in line 5. Specific comment tag is a very logical way to implement it for an ever changing document. If you want to have reference to a line of a file in a source control system. It is much simpler since file is fixed.

Comment: That's an interesting requirement, linking to a specific line of code. What's wrong with `<see cref=""/>` pointing to a class/method/property, etc?

Comment: @jrummell nothing's wrong, though the real problem wasn't on classes, methods and properties I was just waiting for an answer about linking to a specified line of code.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Xml comment + sandcastle may be what you need. You can reference specified class or method using

```
<see cref=".."/>
```

and reference parameters using

```
<paramref name=".."/>
```

However, there is not direct method to reference certain lines of code but you can reference certain #region by using

```
<code source="$sourcefile$" region="$regionname$"/>
```

Please refer to: [XML Comments Guide](http://www.ewoodruff.us/Downloads/XMLDocsGuide.pdf) Page 20.

Note that the code you reference will be displayed directly in place rather than a link. It is not perfect, but I hope it helps.